# Constrain a Key based on the type of its value in a generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a generic function where the generic type is used to type its parameter.

Here's a part of this parameter :

```js
type Configuration<T> = {
    masterdata: T[],
    target: ????
}
```

I'm having trouble typing the `target` property. I would like it to be the name of any property in a specific class (`MtmFormComponent`, the current class) but with the constraint that the type of the property is `T[]`.

My goal is to write : `this[configuration.target] = configuration.masterdata;`.

I'm halfway there. Here's how I've typed `target` for now:

```js
type MtmFormComponentPropertyOfType<T, K extends keyof MtmFormComponent> = MtmFormComponent[K] extends T[] ? K : never;

type DropdownAutocompleteConfiguration<T, K extends keyof MtmFormComponent> = {
    masterdata: T[],

    targetFilteredList: MtmFormComponentPropertyOfType<T, K>,
};
```

When declaring an object of type `DropdownAutocompleteConfiguration`, all is good and the auto-complete of my IDE correctly constrains me into using only a key which leads to the same type as the value of `masterdata`. So my type seems to be correctly defined.

My problem is when using that object in my generic function:

```js
private setupDropdownAutocompleteBehaviour<T, K extends keyof MtmFormComponent>(configuration: DropdownAutocompleteConfiguration<T, K>): void {
        this[configuration.targetFilteredList] = configuration.masterdata;

        // ...
    }
```

Here, the `this[configuration.targetFilteredList]` expression gives the following error:

> Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'this[Currency[] extends T[] ? "filteredCurrencyList" : never] & this[PriceUnit[] extends T[] ? "filteredPriceUnits" : never] & this[Subscription[] extends T[] ? "subscriptions" : never]'.
> Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'this[Currency[] extends T[] ? "filteredCurrencyList" : never]'.
> Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'Currency[]'.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Currency'.

From what I understand, inside the function, TypeScript fully resolves the type of `this[configuration.targetFilteredList]` instead of relying of the fact that it's `T[]`. From the auto-complete feature of my IDE, I'm sure that I cannot have a value for `target` which would lead to an type incompatible with the one of `masterdata`.

I'm not sure what to do from there :/

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, do you have to make your functions generic over the target property key?

To give a concrete example, suppose `MtmFormComponent` was defined like this

```js
interface MtmFormComponent {
    foo: string[];
    bar: string[];
    baz: number[];
    qux: string;
}
```

Now, we want a type that gives us all the property names of a type `T`, where the property name maps to a value that is a `U[]`. We can define this type like so:

```js
type ArrayValuedProps<T, U> = { [K in keyof T]: (T[K] extends U[] ? K : never) }[keyof T]
```

This way, we get

```
ArrayValuedProps<MtmFormComponent, string> = { foo: "foo"; bar: "bar"; baz: never; qux: never }[keyof MtmFormComponent]
                                           = { foo: "foo"; bar: "bar"; baz: never; qux: never }["foo" | "bar" | "baz" | "qux"]
                                           = "foo" | "bar" | never
                                           = "foo" | "bar"
```

Similarly, `ArrayValuedProps<MtmFormComponent, number>` is equivalent to the type `"baz"`;

Using this, we can define your `Configuration<T>` type like so:

```js
type Configuration<T> = {
    masterdata: T[],
    target: ArrayValuedProps<MtmFormComponent, T>
}
```

and we can completely avoid putting in the target key as a type parameter.